# Getting php codeback as data for ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I have this simpel ajax call to a php page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#imgUpload').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: './php/dataUpload.php',  
            type: 'POST',
            data: {boxId: boxId },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                var box = $(data);
                alert('Do it!');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

On change the js-code will executed and I get a response from the php code. I don't know why however the result is the whole php code and not only the echo's..

The php code is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['boxId'])){
        echo $_POST['boxId'];
    } else {
        echo "blub";
    }
?>
```

It's on a local server. Calling the php code only will echo "blub" to the browser-window so the php-code works.

Here the result of the ajax call if changed it to `<?php echo "blub"; ?>`:

```
"<?php↵ echo "blub";↵?>"
```

Comment: Are you sure about when changes made it goes to `dataUpload.php`? Could you try with simple example like `echo 'hello world';`?

Comment: *"result is the whole php code and not only the echo's."* and *"Calling the php code only will echo "blub" to the browser-window so the php-code works."* is a contraction, isn't it?

Comment: Try opening that php file URL with your browser.. you probably have miss configured PHP..

Comment: @DanFromGermany : I think he can't able to tell that clearly.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: calling a php-page over the browser is not the problem, it's only by calling with ajax...

Comment: there is no relevant difference between an ajax request and a request made by the browser through the addressbar. It must be the same response. PHP is just not active/loaded/installed/configured on your localhost.

Comment: Than tell me why I get no error on calling http://localhost/Homepage/php/dataUpload.php with the browser just the plain text blub..

Comment: @user2457241 right click and "view source" of the site, there is PHP code in.

Comment: no there is only one line with the content "blub" nothing else